# Include a binary in applescript bundle?

Tags: applescript, homebrew, binary

I've got an applescript that calls a binary on my computer (installed with homebrew). I'd like to share the applescript with friends, but can't guarantee that they'll have the binary.

For example, a simple app uses `pdfimages` to extract images from a PDF. That binary relies on libraries installed along with it, so if I just include a copy of the binary inside the Contents/Resources folder and reference it, that won't reliably work.

So, is there a way to easily(!) include the binary and its dependencies? I suspect I need to use a different tool for this.

Thanks.

Comment: I am guessing that these dependencies are the rest of the xpdf/poppler package?

Comment: `pdfimages` from the **Mac 64-bit: download** link http://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html is a standalone executable without any dependancies. You can use that one and freely redistribute it if you include all of the documentation: README, man pages (or help files), COPYING, and COPYING3.

Comment: In his case, yes, it’s poppler, but the question is a more general one. So it sounds like the answer is to look for standalone executables?